# External DB URL issues with Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, calendar

I have searched SO and around the web for days trying to solve this issue.

We have a calendar on our WordPress site that links to an external database.

http://flapperscomedy.com/wp/calendar-demo-2/?pg=calendarmonth_page&month=12&year=2015&datefield&meetid&session_type&venue_id=Burbank&room=Main%20Room

The calendar works great, however, if a user tries to go to events in 2016 (or go back to 2014), our WordPress site returns an "Oops! That page cannot be found" error.

We know the error is not from our external database or calendar.php file, as these work perfectly fine when not inside of WordPress.

The error appears to be that Wordpress only recognizes the php-generated URL if the year is current (2015). However, if "&year=2014" or "&year=2016," they receive an "Oops! That page cannot be found" error.

Any guidance on this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are their events for 2016 in the db?

Comment: You should only receive a 404 when either WordPress can not match the given URL via the [Rewrite API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API) or when a plugin calls [$wp_query->set_404()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/set_404/) due to some other qualification.

So my question here is, how are you processing the URL that actually does work? How does WordPress even know what to show at all on that page? Tell us about what you _are_ doing and perhaps we can help you figure out what to do next.